# How to find the displacement of an arbitrary point on a spring?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, applied-mechanics

Consider a spring fixed from end A and pulled from the other end B. The displacement of the end B of the spring is $x$.

[image]

If I take a point at a distance $l_1$ from end A, how can I determine the displacement of this point corresponding to the displacement of end B, which is $x$?

The free (undeformed) length of the spring is $L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to know (or make assumptions about) how the spring is constructed.

If the spring is a nice uniform spring of the sort found in textbook illustrations, then you can figure that each section of the spring elongates by the same amount as any other.  So if the total spring length is $l_t$, and it elongates by $x$ overall, than any section will elongate by a factor of $\frac{l_t} x$.

You can check this for yourself by breaking your textbook spring with spring rate $k$ into $N$ shorter springs of equal length, each with spring rate $\frac k N$, and doing the math on how much extension you get from pulling on the whole assembly in series, and how much any set of $n$ springs will extend at the same time.  Then for any arbitrary fraction of the spring length, find the limit as $N \to \infty$.

If the spring *isn't* nice an uniform, then the stiffer sections will have less proportional elongation than the sections with more compliance; in that case life gets difficult, but with a knowledge of the incremental spring rate (or, better, compliance) along the length of the spring you could determine this elongation by integrating the spring compliance along the length of the section of interest.